# Performance issues for large(ish) server-generated SVG in AngularJS 1.x application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, svg

I have a web application, the front end uses AngularJS 1.x

At certain points an SVG file is generated by the server, dynamically based on user selection. This then needs to be displayed within the Angular-based web page. The SVG can be large-ish (~3.0 MB) but nothing ridiculous. The generation of the SVG is pretty fast and a URL is returned to the browser, downloading it is also pretty fast.

I've noticed that if I just point the browser at the URL, it renders it pretty quickly, on both Chrome and IE.

I can include the SVG inside the Angular app using [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude). This takes a few seconds to update on Chrome which is not brilliant. In IE 11 it takes about a minute which is awful.

What are my options for improving this? Ideally keeping the server-side generation and staying within AngularJS 1.x.